# Migration from JBOSS-3.3.2 to JBOSS EAP 7.1

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I am in process of migrating one of our web application from JBOSS-3.3.2 to JBOSS EAP 7.1. As Jboss 3 will not support JDK1.8*. I was instructed to migrate the jboss to latest jboss version available in our repository.

I referred the following link but it confuses me as both the versions folder structures are different.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html-single/installation_guide

One thing I understood is I have to use standalone/deployments folder for my application(war) to be deployed.

In 3.x we have run.jar, run.sh, run.conf. But in newer versions these are not available instead we have jboss-eap.conf, jboss-eap-rhel.sh but no run.jar any where.

Is there any guide or steps available to be followed for migration.

I was not able to find in google.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest JBoss EAP, you have to start the JBoss EAP server using standalone.sh (for standalone mode) or domain.sh(for domain mode) file.

The .sh file is located under $JBOSS_HOME/bin directory.

For configuration, you can configure using standalone.conf or standalone.xml file in standalone mode and for domain mode, you have to add configuration inside domain.xml file.

For migration please refer to the official document.